# Rails: rpush gem does not sending push with --no-error-checks options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I use https://github.com/rpush/rpush gem for sending push notifications for APNS server. It works fine, but when i turn on --no-error-checks options for rpush process, push message not delivered on device. But log file has not any mistake.
Without this options process is very slowly... I need send more than 200k notifications.

What can be wrong with rpush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are disabling the error checking, you run the risk of having some invalid device tokens at the start of your tokens list, which prevent the delivery of any valid tokens that follow. You should turn off `--no-error-checks` at least once, to identify the invalid device tokens and remove them from your DB. Once you make sure all your device tokens are valid, you can safely turn `--no-error-checks` back on.

> If you find that notifications aren't getting through, but you get no
>   feedback or validation problems, check the rpush logs for EPIPE errors
>   and reconnections. An occasional lapse is to be expected, but if you
>   get one on every request it means that Apple is dropping the
>   connection before the rest of the batch can be sent.
>
> The most likely explanation for the drop is that you're sending a
>   sandbox token to the production service. It could also happen if your
>   payload was too long, but rpush validation would normally catch that
>   first.
>
> Naturally, the dev token is usually first in the list, so nothing
>   comes through and the whole system looks broken.
>
> I don't think it's possible to tell the difference between a sandbox
>   and a production token, so the only way to be sure of avoiding this is
>   to do as apple recommends, and run a separate instance of your
>   provider (and/or token-gatherer) for each push environment.

Comment: Thank you! You have confirmed my version.

Comment: Also note that in RPush, your key must correspond with the environment of your app. Using development key in app whose environment is production results in `Error received, reconnecting`